# version numbers in gradle

Tags: gradle

Anyone know how to get this working in gradle for a SUBPROJECT so that running the left hand size results in the right hand archive name...

```
gradle assemble -> databus-Developer-Build.zip
gradle -DmyVersion=1.0.2 assemble -> databus-1.0.2.zip
OR
gradle -PmyVersion=1.0.2 assemble -> databas-1.0.2.zip
```

I have tried and tried with a variable myVersion but it always says it does not exist....and in half the cases, it shouldn't exist because I didn't supply it!!!!!

How to get this working in a subproject?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add following snippet to `allprojects` configuration section of root build.gradle:

```
allprojects {

   if (project.hasProperty('myVersion')) {
     project.version = project.myVersion
   } else {
     project.version = 'Developer-Build'
   }

}
```

and than pass your version in command line as `-PmyVersion=1.0.2`. Tested with rather old Gradle 1.0-milestone-3

Answer (score 0):

proper way to do it in newer versions worked...(notice the ext addition).

```
   if (project.hasProperty('myVersion')) {
     project.ext.xVersion = project.myVersion
   } else {
     project.ext.xVersion = 'Developer-Build'
   }
```

and interestingly enough this one does NOT work because 'version' seems to be some sort of reserverd property and is set to unspecified on startup...

```
   if (project.hasProperty('version')) {
     project.ext.xVersion = project.version
   } else {
     project.ext.xVersion = 'Developer-Build'
   }
```

Seeing as version seems to be a reserved property, it is most likely used in publishing artifacts so the best solution then maybe the following

```
   if (project.hasProperty('myVersion')) {
     project.version = project.myVersion
   } else {
     project.version = 'Developer-Build'
   }
```

and the automated build passes in myVersion and developers of course don't.